# Python - Summarizing Tweets DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, sentiment-analysis

1. I am dealing with Twitter Sentiment Analysis, mining tweets for certain specific keywords.
2. I am able to store the tweets as well as process them, generating sentiments and subjectivity etc.
3. I have a list of 200 keywords on which I am extracting tweets and storing them and processing them together.
4. but, I need this to be summarized based on all tweets that I have overall. I have create column.

Comment: Do tweets with two keywords count twice in the table?

Comment: And what is overall sentiment anyway? Is it the mode? (And then, is overall subjectivity the average?)

Comment: @tmrlvi, the overall sentiment is the average by class (or search term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each tweet can have multiple keywords, I don't think there is a clean way to do it. My solution would be to create a `pd.Series` out of the keywords, and use `apply` to loop through the keywords.

Assume that the list you provided above is in the variable `keywords`, and `DataFrame` of tweets is in `df`. I'm also assuming that *Overall Sentiment Score* is the most common sentiment, and the *Overall Subjectivity* is the mean.

```
def summarize(data):
    """
    Extract the statistics for a given sub-dataframe
    """
    return pd.Series({
                      "total_tweets" : len(data)
                      "total_retweets" : data.retweet_count.sum()
                      "total_favorites" : data.favorite_count.sum()
                      "total_comments" : data.reply_count.sum()
                      "overall_sentiment_score" : data.sentiment.mode().loc[0]
                      "overall_subjectivity" : data.subjectivity.mean()
                     })

s = pd.Series(keywords)
res = s.apply(lambda word: summarize(df[df.text.str.contains(word)]))
```

Comment: It didn't worked. an you please check it with the CSV file, I have attached in the question above, Also, I put all commas in pd.Series and also removed, .loc[0]. but i get is empty, NaNs,  and 0s.

Comment: Error id pointing towards> "overall_sentiment_score" : data.sentiment.mode().iloc[0],

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: its because, for some keywords its nan, or empty, so it is throwing that error.

Comment: I changed you solution a bit, and it worked. Thanks a lot.